# view on top of tableview shows up below

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view, tableview

I have a on top of my tableview another view with 3 buttons on it. You can see my [storyboard](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8108627410/in/photostream) over here.

When I build and run. This view shows up at the bottom of my tableview. Someone has an idea how this is possible?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIView` is subview of `UITableView`, to make it on top of the tableView, just drag it out of `UITableView` scope.

Comment: and put the tableview inside the uiview?

Comment: I can see from your snapshot that the view is under the tableView, which mean it's a subview for the tableView, when you try drag the view, it will highlight the superView, in your case, the tableView will be highlighted, Try drag it to match the level of tableView and NavigationItem.

Comment: I think that is not possible. Everytime I want to do that. My view replaced the tableview

Comment: Upload your project to let me download it and upload it to you again, if you want.

Comment: please provide an e-mail adres so that I can send you it

Answer (score 0):

If you select the UITableView then in the Xcode menu Editor->Embed In->View

This will embed the UITableView in a UIView. You can then drag your UIView out from the UITableView and place it at the same level as your UITableView.